# 3 equal right vertical bars in latex

Tags: equations, align, bar

I am trying to write the following equation in latex.

[image: required equation]

But I am not getting it. I have tried many times. My MME is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{align*}
        &= \left. \left. \left. \left(  \frac{-2}{3} R^5\phi cos^3 \theta   \right)  \right|_{R=0}^{2}\right|_{\theta = 0}^{\phi/4}\right|_{\phi = 0}^{2\pi}
    \end{align*}
    
\end{document}
```

It's output is as:
[image: latex output]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fixed size delimiters, also `\cos` not `cos`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    
    
\[
        = \biggl(  \frac{-2}{3} R^5\phi \cos^3 \theta   \biggr)  \biggr|_{R=0}^{2}\biggr|_{\theta = 0}^{\phi/4}\biggr|_{\phi = 0}^{2\pi}
\]
    
\end{document}
```